# Use cases when Iterator Pattern is used

Tags: design-patterns

I am novice to Software Development, I was studying the Iterator Pattern as documented in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern) . I got the general understanding but Could someone give a use-case example of where this pattern is useful.

Comment: What is it you don't understand? Can you explain in more detail? This is a classic case of separating a functionality from an implementation. Imagine you have data about all university students stored in an array, and you ask me to write a function that finds the student with highest computer science grade. I write the function. Tomorrow you decide to store the student data in a binary tree instead of the array, because it might be more efficient for some purposes. Is the function I wrote today still valid? If I explicitly referenced the array, no. If I used a more general iterator, yes.

Comment: Wikipedia is not a good source for learning design patterns. I would suggest [sourcemaking](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns) and [refactoring.guru](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iterator design pattern is in the behavioral design pattern in [GoF patterns](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/what-is-pattern).

this is not a weird pattern! this pattern just helps you to have an easy way to making a collection and access to iterate on its element. in other words, this pattern provides an effective way of accessing elements of a collection sequentially, without knowing how the collection is structured.

the main idea is that an aggregate object such as an array or list will give you a way to access its elements without exposing its internal structure.

you can use this pattern to handle iteration on a collection, Even in some languages like c#, to make it simple, there is a built-in implementation of iterate pattern(Ex: [IEnumerable](https://www.dotnetperls.com/ienumerable) is an implementation of iterator pattern to help you simply access your collection such as records in database table collection and so on).

for more useful information and a simple tutorial you could see the following link:

https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/iterator

and also here and a simple example (c#) a list that can iterate with an iterator:

```
class Program
{
    public class Weeks //Aggregate object
    {
        private string[] weeks = new string[]{
            "Monday",
            "Tuesday",
            "Wednesday",
            "Thursday",
            "Friday",
            "Saturday",
            "Sunday"
            };

        public IWeeksIterator GetWeeksIterator()
        {
            //creates an Iterator object
            return new WeeksIterator(weeks);
        }
    }

    public interface IWeeksIterator //Iterator interface
    {
        string Current { get; }

        bool MoveNext();
    }

    public class WeeksIterator : IWeeksIterator //Iterator object
    {
        private readonly string[] weeks;
        private int position;

        public WeeksIterator(string[] weeks)
        {
            this.weeks = weeks;
            this.position = -1;
        }

        public string Current => weeks[position];

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            if (++position == weeks.Length) return false;
            return true;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var weeks = new Weeks();
        var iterator = weeks.GetWeeksIterator();
        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(iterator.Current);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```